# KeyCode is taking wrong in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

My javascript code to disable decimals in textbox ix like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".money-input").keypress(function (e) {
        // between 0 and 9
        if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
            alert(1);
            showAdvice(this, "Integer values only");
            return (false);  // stop processing
        }
    });

    function showAdvice(obj, msg) {
        $("#singleAdvice").stop(true, false).remove();  // remove any prev msg
        $('<span id="singleAdvice" class="advice">' + msg + '</span>').insertAfter(obj);
        $("#singleAdvice").delay(4000).fadeOut(1500);  // show for 4 seconds, then fade out
    }
});
```

This works perfect in Chrome. But when i go to Mozilla. Back space alos get in to that if case. So when I press back space nothing happens and error message is shown. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong herE?

Comment: what did actually you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keypress` event does not fire for non-printable characters, like <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and in your case, backspace.

Use `keyup()` instead:

```
$(".money-input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
        showAdvice(this, "Integer values only");
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mytrz94y/)

Comment: I want to disable decimal values inside that textbox as i made in my original code. but with your code it is not happening

Comment: Well that was already solved in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279047/how-to-prevent-user-from-entering-decimals) which seems to be the source of the code you have

Comment: Yes, but they solved it with Keypress event and which makes the new issue in Mozilla. Now what I am trying to do is to make decimal disable and the same time backspace also works, Isn't there anyway to make it?

Comment: No, it is not. atleast in Mozilla.
http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CkDTy/