# Preventing User from entering Decimals using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Java Script .I want to prevent the user from entering decimals 
 in a field using JavaScript. I tried this method but showing this error .

Syntax error on token "_$tag____________", invalid AssignmentOperator

```
<td>
<form:input class="form-control line_qty_class inputs" onkeypress="checkDecimal();" required="required" id="line_qty${loop.index}" path="saleInvoiceLines[${loop.index}].quantity" />
</td>


<script>
function checkDecimal() {
    $(".line_qty").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which < 46 || e.which > 57) {
            showAdvice(this, "Enter Integer Value");
            return(false);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent user from entering decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279047/how-to-prevent-user-from-entering-decimals)

Comment: You don't have a `line_qty` class and your binding your onclick everytime you click the input. And nothing in that page will generate that error message.

Comment: $(".line_qty_class").keypress(function(e).. But i changed it but still showing the same error

Comment: **And nothing in that page will generate that error message.**

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**

```js
$(".line_qty").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which < 46 || e.which > 57) {
    console.log("Enter Integer Value");
    return (false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input class="line_qty" required="required" id="line_qty" />
</td>
```

**What was wrong?**

1. You assinged to `onkyepress` function which adds event on `keypress`. That's pointless. Either just add a function that fires on `keypress` or use `onkeypress`,
2. You wrote in jQuery class `line_qty` but your element did not have that class. It had class `line_qty_class` which is different,
3. You use a function `showAdvice()` which is not defined, but maybe you have that function defined so it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery keydown() Method to Preventing User from entering Decimals:

```js
$(function() {
  $( '#txtinteger' ).on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
    -1 !== $.inArray( e.keyCode, [ 46,8,9,27,13,110,190 ] ) || ( /65|67|86|88/.test( e.keyCode ) && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) && ( !0 === e.ctrlKey || !0 === e.metaKey ) || 35 <= e.keyCode && 40 >= e.keyCode || ( e.shiftKey || 48 > e.keyCode || 57 < e.keyCode ) && ( 96 > e.keyCode || 105 < e.keyCode ) && e.preventDefault()
  } );
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtinteger" />
```